# functional tests=Integration Tests ？in django

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, integration

Recently,I am studying about django test. Because I need to build unittest and integration test in my website.But I find that the tutorial of integration test in django is really less and it often occurs when I hit a link named "**integration test**" ,I only see the title "functional tests".So,are they the same? if not,how can I start a integrstion test in django?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot compare these notions.

The opposite to *integration testing* is *unit testing*. *Unit testing* - is testing different isolated parts (usually small code blocks) of your system separately - it's very focused, *integration testing* is testing how these different parts of your system work together - for example, url routing, logic in views, logging, querying your models etc.

*Functional testing* is a type of black box testing that usually checks that some (usually documented) piece of functionality works as expected.

You may have all sorts of tests in your django project:

- unit tests of different library, helper functions
- view tests (this could be already called integration tests, because it may include dealing with models, logging etc)
- ui tests (high-level tests, that could be called functional/integration/system)
- ..

If you don't have tests at all, I'd start with high-level tests. For example, I'd take [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) and [django_selenium](https://github.com/dragoon/django-selenium) and write some in-browser tests that will go through pre-defined scenarios, like `login->do smth->logoff`, `login with incorrect credentials->see error` etc - and these tests would be called *functional* and *system* and *integration* and *ui* and etc - you got it I think.

See also:

- [Testing Django Applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/)
- [A Guide to Testing in Django](http://toastdriven.com/blog/2011/apr/10/guide-to-testing-in-django/)
- [Carl Mayer's "Testing and Django" slides](http://carljm.github.io/django-testing-slides/)
- [Integration Testing in Python](http://www.slideshare.net/panopticdev/integration-testing-in-python)

Hope that helps.

Comment: That is to say,I don't use the " https://github.com/hackrole/django-TDD/blob/master/fts/tests.py " as a integration test. So well, do you have some tutorials about integration test in django?

Comment: Yup, last 2 links should definitely help.

Comment: Oh,that's great!Thank you for your help.By the way,I can't see the last page,maybe it is because of I'm from "somecountry".

Comment: Would you like to send me an email with the contents of the last tutorial "Integration Testing in Python" ?

Comment: Can you see it [here](http://leone.panopticdev.com/2012/04/integration-testing-in-python.html)?

Comment: only  "Hey folks!  Here's a presentation I did for the Providence Royal Python Society meetup this winter.  It covers some of the currently-available integration testing tools for Python, as well as my own project, easy-integration. 
 "

Comment: Encouraging people to start the foundation of their tests with high level browser tests is bad advice.

Comment: @mmla ok, no, it is not.